# Node.js module.exports in CoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm working on a simple example; I can get it to work with Javascript, but there is something wrong with my CoffeeScript version.

Here is person.coffee:

```
module.exports = Person

class Person 
    constructor: (@name) ->

    talk: ->
        console.log "My name is #{@name}"
```

And here is index.coffee:

```
Person = require "./person"
emma = new Person "Emma"
emma.talk()
```

I am expecting to run index.coffee and see the console output "My name is Emma".  Instead, I am getting an error saying TypeError: undefined in not a function.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Put the `module.exports` line at the bottom.

----person.coffee----

```
class Person 
    constructor: (@name) ->

    talk: ->
        console.log "My name is #{@name}"

module.exports = Person
```

---

```
Person = require "./person" // [Function: Person]
p = new Person "Emma" // { name: 'Emma' }
```

When you assign to `module.exports` at the top, the `Person` variable is still `undefined`.

Comment: fyi: to understand why it could be usefull to look at the traditional pattern in javascript to make modules

Answer (score 16):

You could also write in `person.coffee`:

```
class @Person
```

Then use the following in `index.coffee`:

```
{Person} = require './person'
```

Comment: Tried this and kept getting `object is not a function` error.

Comment: @majidarif Take a look at your compiled code to check it is making sense. Are you running in a Node.js environment or browser?

Comment: I'm actually on Node.js, I have 2 classes on 1 file, and 2 class that extends one and one of those class. Then the subcass are the one I needed to export.

Answer (score 5):

You could also write

```
module.exports = class Person
  constructor: (@name) ->
    console.log "#{@name} is a person"
```

then in `index.coffee` either

```
bob = new require './person' 'Bob'
```

or you could do it this way

```
Person = require './person'
bob = new Person 'bob'
```

Answer (score 2):

The various answers here seems to take for granted that the only one object exported by the module is the class (kind of "Java way of thinking")

If you need to export several objects (classes, functions, etc), it should probably be best to write:

```
exports.Person = class Person
    [...]
```

```
coffee> { Person } = require "./person"
coffee> p = new Person "Emma"
```